# RDS instance does not create in localstack

Tags: terraform, localstack

I am using terraform to create an RDS istance in localstack. I am using a very simple example which is using the a code example from the RDS/terraform docs. This is what it looks like. If i dont include this, the other resources such as SQS/SNS/S3 create fine.

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "test-rds" {
  allocated_storage    = 5
  storage_type         = "gp2"
  engine               = "postgres"
  engine_version       = "5.7"
  instance_class       = "db.t2.micro"
  name                 = "mydb"
  username             = "foo"
  password             = "foobarbaz"
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.7"
}
```

There is no error when creating the RDS instance but it says

> innovation_1  | module.db.aws_db_instance.test-rds: Still creating...
>   [11s elapsed] localstack_1  |
>   2020-02-10T21:05:39:INFO:localstack_ext.services.rds.rds_listener:
>   Starting RDS server on port 4511 - database "mydb", user "foo"
>   localstack_1  |
>   2020-02-10T21:05:44:INFO:localstack_ext.services.rds.rds_listener:
>   Starting RDS server on port 4511 - database "mydb", user "foo"
>   innovation_1  | module.db.aws_db_instance.test-rds: Still creating...
>   [20s elapsed] localstack_1  |
>   2020-02-10T21:05:53:INFO:localstack_ext.services.rds.rds_listener:
>   Starting RDS server on port 4511 - database "mydb", user "foo"

Forever. I waited one time for 20 minutes and this message was still printing to the terminal.

In addition I am using the localstack pro version with the following docker-compose file

```
services:
  innovation:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - localstack
    links:
    - localstack
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
    - "4567-4584:4567-4584"
    environment:
    - SERVICES=s3:4572,sns:4575,sqs:4576,rds:4578
    - LOCALSTACK_API_KEY=sdfsdf
```

The terraform provider file looks like this

```
terraform {
  backend "local" {}
}

provider "aws" {
  access_key                  = "mock_access_key"
  region                      = "us-east-1"
  s3_force_path_style         = true
  secret_key                  = "mock_secret_key"
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
  skip_requesting_account_id  = true

  endpoints {
    apigateway     = "http://localstack:4567"
    cloudformation = "http://localstack:4581"
    cloudwatch     = "http://localstack:4582"
    dynamodb       = "http://localstack:4569"
    es             = "http://localstack:4578"
    firehose       = "http://localstack:4573"
    iam            = "http://localstack:4593"
    kinesis        = "http://localstack:4568"
    lambda         = "http://localstack:4574"
    route53        = "http://localstack:4580"
    redshift       = "http://localstack:4577"
    s3             = "http://localstack:4572"
    secretsmanager = "http://localstack:4584"
    ses            = "http://localstack:4579"
    sns            = "http://localstack:4575"
    sqs            = "http://localstack:4576"
    ssm            = "http://localstack:4583"
    stepfunctions  = "http://localstack:4585"
    sts            = "http://localstack:4592"
    rds            = "http://localstack:4578"
  }
}
```

Why is this happening? How does one create an RDS instance with terraform in localstack? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the Pro version of localstack? It seems that RDS is only available in the Pro version of localstack https://github.com/localstack/localstack

Also, can you post your provider configuration?

Comment: I am using pro version.

Comment: Hi can you confirm to use Redshift with LocalStack, you need the Pro version ?

Comment: In your docker compose, update the image to `localstack/localstack-pro`. May not have been the case when you asked the question, but it is now. Also, all endpoints should now be reachable on port `4566`. No need for the `SERVICES` env var anymore as well.